# NSOperationQueue error: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code = 2, address = 0x4)

Tags: objective-c, nsoperationqueue

I like to create an `NSOperationQueue`, the `NSOperatioQueue` should refresh a `UILable`, I created this code:

```
NSOperationQueue * ramQueue = [NSOperationQueue alloc];
    [ramQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{
        while (TRUE) {

            //Creating String

            NSOperationQueue *main = [NSOperationQueue mainQueue];
            [main addOperationWithBlock:^{

                //Refresh Label

            }];

        }

    }];
```

But it wont work, the label isnt showing the new strings. is is showing an error here: `[ramQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{`

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Please provide more detail about what you are trying to achieve. What do you mean by refresh the UILabel? Why are you nesting 2 `addOperationWithBlock:` calls?

Comment: Presumably to kick work back to the main queue for UI updates. I'm more worried about the `while(TRUE)` loop - seems like that one operation will run for quite some time, potentially either starving the main queue of operation time or overloading it with new block operations (or both!).

Comment: An `init` for `ramQueue` may not be necessary but I always feel better when I see one.  :)

Comment: @AlfieHanssen That nested structure, where you have a background queue that, itself, later adds operations back to the main queue, is a very common and very useful technique. You cannot do UI updates from the background, so David's technique of nesting a call to the main queue from a background queue is not only fine, but often necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of thoughts:

1. That `[NSOperationQueue alloc]` should be `[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init]`.
2. I'd generally advise against a never ending  `while` loop. If you want to repeatedly do something, a repeating timer (at some reasonable rate, probably not more than 10-20 times per second) might be a better construct. If you use the `while` loop construct, you could easily end up posting operations to the main queue faster than the main loop can process them. (It depends upon what's inside that `while` loop.)
3. If you stay with that `while` loop (which, again, I'd discourage you from doing), you probably want an `@autoreleasepool` inside there so any auto released objects get deallocated.

   ```
   [ramQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{
       while (TRUE) {
           @autoreleasepool {
               //Creating String

               NSOperationQueue *main = [NSOperationQueue mainQueue];
               [main addOperationWithBlock:^{

                   //Refresh Label
               }];
           }
       }
   }];
   ```

   You might even want to use semaphores to ensure the background operation doesn't post events too quickly.
4. Probably unrelated to your problem, but if you're doing anything that is updating any shared resources (e.g. changing any class properties or ivars), make sure to synchronize those with the main queue. You can do that by dispatching those updates back to the main queue or employ some locking mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I wanna thank Rob, for pointing me in the right direction!

here is my right code:

First of all I created `[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 target:self selector:@selector(updateRam) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];` instead of the `while(TRUE){}` loop. then I corrected my `NSOperationQueue` code like this:

```
-(void)updateRam {

    NSOperationQueue * ramQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [ramQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{

        //Create String

        NSOperationQueue *main = [NSOperationQueue mainQueue];
        [main addOperationWithBlock:^{

         //Refresh Label

        }];

    }];
}
```

Thanks agan!